# Parallax scrolling effect works but my image won't pin to both sides and to top of page

Tags: html, css, padding, margins

I started working with HTML and CSS, I’m trying to make a project with parallax scrolling. I took the existing code from this for the parallax effect [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)

The parallax effect works, but the image has a barrier between it and the end of the page.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

My HTML and CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

html {
background-color: rgb(228, 210, 210);
}

.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  min-height: 850px; 


  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 95px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 2em;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
  height:500px; 
  background-color:rgb(21, 106, 112); 
  color: rgb(175, 174, 174);
  font-size:32px;
  border-radius: 25px; 
  padding: 15px 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.div2 {
  height:500px; 
  background-color:rgb(60, 219, 153); 
  color: rgb(92, 91, 91);
  font-size:32px;
  border-radius: 25px; 
  padding: 15px 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

ul, ul > h1 > li, #skills {
  color: rgb(102, 101, 101);
  list-style-type: square;
}

#sideprojects {
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-base {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(29, 28, 28);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="css\style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
      <body>
      
      <div class="parallax">
          <h1>name</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="nav-base">

      </div>
      
      <div class="div1">
          <h1 id="title">Random Title</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc efficitur volutpat fringilla. Morbi eget hendrerit augue. 
          Vestibulum ipsum risus, convallis sed sagittis vitae, tincidunt eget sem. Sed feugiat luctus diam non sollicitudin. 
          Nulla eu lectus bibendum, tempus est porttitor, vulputate metus. Vestibulum nec diam pellentesque, aliquam eros eget, semper magna. Suspendisse aliquam, dui nec accumsan dapibus, mi neque sollicitudin eros, ac fringilla dolor nisi vitae elit. 
          Quisque et vehicula purus. Nulla vestibulum sem nibh, vitae consectetur tortor convallis posuere. Vestibulum nulla libero, tincidunt sit amet suscipit non, rhoncus ut ligula. 
          Morbi tortor mauris, bibendum sit amet lorem vitae, convallis dignissim nisi. In pharetra et odio eu tristique. Nam ullamcorper pharetra nibh, at tincidunt diam.
      </div>

      <div class="div2">
          <h2 id="sideprojects">Side Projects</h2>
          <ul id="skills">
              <h2>Skills</h2>
              <li>Java</li>
              <li>HTML</li>
              <li>CSS</li>
              <li>Wordpress</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      
      </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the default margin that is given to the body tag by the browser which for chrome is 8px (it can vary from browser to browser). This can be overridden in your css if you want with something like this:

```
HTML, body {
margin: 0px;
}
```